# Apache Impala Inner Query restriction for FROM statement

Tags: subquery, impala, inner-query

This IMPALA sub query restriction consumed too much of my time. So I decided to post here to save people some time.

If you are making an inner query for the FROM part you cant make your standard SQL to work.  I.e:

```
select count(*) from (SELECT * from mytable WHERE id="12345")
```

is not working giving the following error.

> ERROR: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1: ...WHERE
>   id="12345")
>                               ^ Encountered: EOF Expected: AS, IDENTIFIER
>
> CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to create a temporary alias (stupidalias) for the inner query result.

```
select count(*) from (SELECT * from mytable WHERE id="12345") as stupidalias
```